# How to find the definition of EVP_MD, EVP_MD_CT, etc in OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl, hmac

I am using OpenSSL. I want to calculate a mac of message using [HMAC](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/HMAC.html) algorithm. The definitions of HMAC is as following:

```
unsigned char *HMAC(const EVP_MD *evp_md, const void *key,
                     int key_len, const unsigned char *d, int n,
                     unsigned char *md, unsigned int *md_len);
```

Now, I find the first parameter of HMAC is [EVP_MD](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_MD_CTX_init.html). I notice that many functions return this parameter. Where can I find the content of EVP_MD in its' reference or source code.

```
 const EVP_MD *EVP_md_null(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_md2(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_md5(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_sha(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_sha1(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_dss(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_dss1(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_mdc2(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_ripemd160(void);

 const EVP_MD *EVP_sha224(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_sha256(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_sha384(void);
 const EVP_MD *EVP_sha512(void);
```

What is the relationship between EVP_MD and EVP_MD_CTX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `EVP_MD` structure contains the description of a hashing algorithm.  The functions you listed return a pointer to one of these structs for a specific hash.  You would pass one of these as the first parameter to `HASH`.

For example, if you wanted to hash with SHA256 you would call `EVP_sha256` and pass its return value to `HASH`.

Comment: Thanks, Where can I find the definition of EVP_MD and EVP_MD_CTX?

Comment: I find it in ```openssl/include/crypto/evp.h```.

Comment: @Land They're internal structures.  You don't need to look inside them.  All you need to do is pass around pointers to them.